# pygame chromebook key names

Tags: python, pygame

I am currently following a pygame tutorial on a chromebook on which i have installed and linux to use IDLE. i am writing a block of code which assigns and x-axis increase or decrase to the arrow keys:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

displayWidth = 800
displayHeight = 600
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
crashed = False
carImg = pygame.image.load('racecar.png')

def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImg, (x,y))
    
x = (displayWidth * 0.45)
y = (displayHeight * 0.8)
x_change = 0
car_speed = 0

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((displayHeight, displayWidth))
pygame.display.set_caption('Zoomer')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = -5
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    x_change = 5
                    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0

    x += x_change

    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

when i try to run the code, the car sprite won't budge. is this due to the fact that i am on chromebook and key names are different or is it an other reason? thanks.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you have wrong indentations.

You check `pygame.KEYDOWN` inside `if ... pygame.QUIT:` which is executed only when you close window.

You need all `if event.type` start in the same column

```
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = -5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 5
                    
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_change = 0
```

Comment: Thank you ! I was in the wrong, my indents were improperly place.